# Creating Random Strings in Python

Tags: python, loops, random

```
import random

string1 = "Fred"
string2 = "Jones"
int1 = 4
int2 = 8
randomInt = random.randint(1, 100)
GloriousListOfFun = [string1, string2, int1, int2, randomInt]
RandomFromGloriousListOfFun = random.choice(GloriousListOfFun)

x=0
while x<1: 
    line1 = "Hi I am {} from Albion".format(RandomFromGloriousListOfFun)
    print(line1)
```

I know this is 99.9% useless but right now this would return something like:
"Hi I am 9 from Albion"
"Hi I am 9 from Albion"
"Hi I am 9 from Albion"
etc...
Does anyone know how I could make it repeat itself like this but with a random variable every time? Thank you.

Comment: You are only using `random.choice` once. You need to make use of it again within the loop. Give it a go.

Comment: You may want to know about Faker https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html if you want to generate convincing random stuff to populate a faked-up database for testing or anything like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your mistake is here

```
RandomFromGloriousListOfFun = random.choice(GloriousListOfFun)
```

as it makes your random fixed! what you should be doing is running `random.choice(GloriousListOfFun)` every time, like this:

```
while x<1: 
    line1 = "Hi I am {} from Albion".format(random.choice(GloriousListOfFun))
    print(line1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `RandomFromGloriousListOfFun` a function and call it at each iteration so it returns a random sample from the list each time:

```
GloriousListOfFun = [string1, string2, int1, int2, randomInt]
RandomFromGloriousListOfFun = lambda: random.choice(GloriousListOfFun)

for _ in range(5):
    print("Hi I am {} from Albion".format(RandomFromGloriousListOfFun()))
```

**Output**

```
Hi I am 97 from Albion
Hi I am Fred from Albion
Hi I am 8 from Albion
Hi I am Jones from Albion
Hi I am 8 from Albion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put those randoms into while loop so every time it will get new random.

```
import random

string1 = "Fred"
string2 = "Jones"
int1 = 4
int2 = 8
x=0
while x<1:
    randomInt = random.randint(1, 100)
    GloriousListOfFun = [string1, string2, int1, int2, randomInt]
    RandomFromGloriousListOfFun = random.choice(GloriousListOfFun)
    line1 = "Hi I am {} from Albion".format(RandomFromGloriousListOfFun)
    print(line1)
```